Depthmap from picture taken via wasm/html?
Is there a way as of the end of 2024 to retrieve the associated depth map from a picture taken inside a mobile wasm app ?
Older sources talk about the depth api or native dev. Not the usecase here.
Last resort is html5.
Thanks,
